# Request queries not passing tests

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, response

I am struggling to pass this test on a freeCodeCamp project: "You can add from, to and limit parameters to a GET /api/users/:_id/logs request to retrieve part of the log of any user. from and to are dates in yyyy-mm-dd format. limit is an integer of how many logs to send back.
"

Here is the an example of the expected response:

```
{
  username: "fcc_test",
  count: 1,
  _id: "5fb5853f734231456ccb3b05",
  log: [{
    description: "test",
    duration: 60,
    date: "Mon Jan 01 1990",
  }]
}
```

I am returning the same as the example response

Here is my database query function:

```
export const fetchExerciseLogs = async (
    userId: string,
    from?: string,
    to?: string,
    limit?: string
): Promise<FetchExerciseLogsResult | undefined> => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    const foundId: User | null = await UserModel.findById(userId)

    // using username to find exercises associated with it
    const exerciseQuery: exerciseQuery = {}
    if (foundId) {
        exerciseQuery.username = foundId.username;
    }

    // if there are request queries for date, add those to the query object
    if (from && to) {
        const fromDate = new Date(from);
        const toDate = new Date(to);
        exerciseQuery.date = { $gte: fromDate, $lte: toDate };
    }

    // if there is a limit query, change it to a number
    let limitNumber: number = 9999
    if (limit) {
        limitNumber = parseFloat(limit);
    }

    // find all exercises in the db that match the username and any date and/or limit queries
    const foundExercises = await ExerciseModel.find(exerciseQuery).limit(limitNumber).exec()

    let logArray: ExerciseDetails[] | undefined = foundExercises.map((exercise) => {
        return {
            description: exercise.description,
            duration: exercise.duration,
            date: exercise.date,
        };
    })
    // if there's a limit query - return log array no longer than the limit
    if (limitNumber) {
        logArray = logArray.slice(0, limitNumber + 1)
    }

    const numOfExercises: number = logArray.length;

    const exerciseLog: FetchExerciseLogsResult = {
        username: foundExercises[0]?.username || "no username found",
        count: numOfExercises,
        _id: userId,
        log: logArray.length > 0 ? logArray : "no logs found"
    }
    return exerciseLog
};
```

Or alternatively, you can find the replit full code here: https://replit.com/@nicole-lancaste/boilerplate-project-exercisetracker

I have tried returning an empty array instead of the "no logs found" however this did not pass the test either. Thanks

Link to project requirements and user stories --> https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/back-end-development-and-apis/back-end-development-and-apis-projects/exercise-tracker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to sort the issues and got all tests passing.

Initially I changed the date format from `toDateString()` to `toUTCString()` however it appears Mongoose doesn't compare dates correctly in this format.

Last test passed with ensuring dates were stored in database using `toISOString()` and only using the `toDateString()` format when sending the response back to the user in the exercise/logs objects.